# how do i add python 2.7 in heroku environment for node app?

Tags: python, heroku

I am working on node app where in one use case I am calling python script through node using `python-shell` ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell). I am trying to deploy this app on heroku but heroku only detects node app and does not includes python in environment.

I tried adding python build stack but Heroku throws error "App not compatible with buildpack".

Comment: Have you read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app?

Comment: Yes, I have and I tried running app by adding node and python build pack but it says app is not compatible with python build pack

Comment: Do you just need the Python to build something, or at runtime? The issue is probably that most buildpacks are designed to run an app in a single runtime language. The compatibility is probably a lack of e.g. `setup.py` or `requirements.txt` to tell it what to build. You may need to look into a custom buildpack that can provide a runtime environment with multiple languages.

Comment: I need python just at runtime to run some scripts

Comment: I tried runtime.txt with python-2.7.15 but still, it is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by creating requirement.txt with random packages like numpy==1.16.2. If you don't mind extra dependencies this will do the trick.

Comment: Don't add "random packages" or "extra dependencies". An empty `requirements.txt` should suffice.